# How to dynamically assign valdr rules?

Tags: angularjs, valdr

Forgive my minimal knowledge of AngularJS and valdr...

I have an application using AngularJS where the ui is dynamically generated to edit some object with meta-data provided to determine the type to interpret the members of the object. I'm going to add extra meta-data to set validation rules for each member.

I found valdr and I wondered if it might be possible to add the rules using `valdrProvider.addConstraints()` called repeatedly for each editable field. Presumably the rule names would have to be made unique?

How could I remove rules from the rule set when data was unloaded?

Is this approach valid  or should I just map the rule meta data directly using an AngularJS directive or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach sounds ok. valdr offers a [`removeConstraint(constraintName)`](https://github.com/netceteragroup/valdr/blob/master/src/core/valdr-service.js#L28) function that might do what you need. Note, however, that this removes all contraints for a given model type.

Take the example at https://github.com/netceteragroup/valdr#getting-started.

```
yourApp.config(function(valdrProvider) {
  valdrProvider.addConstraints({
    'Person': {
      'lastName': {
        'size': {
          'min': 2,
          'max': 10,
          'message': 'Last name must be between 2 and 10 characters.'
        },
        'required': {
          'message': 'Last name is required.'
        }
      },
      'firstName': {
        'size': {
          'min': 2,
          'max': 20,
          'message': 'First name must be between 2 and 20 characters.'
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Calling `removeConstraint('Person')` would remove *all* constraints for `Person`. If you just want to remove the `firstName` because you remove the first name input field you can call `addConstraints` again with an updated constraints definition for `Person`.

Final notes:

- valdr doesn't impose you remove constraints if fields are removed (see discussion at https://github.com/netceteragroup/valdr/issues/46)
- yes, constraint names are unique because they are bound to model types which should have unique names, there shouldn't be two `Person` types with different implementation